# Should a ProgressBar wait for a moment after reaching 100%?

Tags: android, firebase, progressdialog

I was about to get my hands on `ProgressDialog` for the first time, so I have no experience with it. But with API 26 it became deprecated and we should use a `ProgressBar` instead.
This is my simple implementation (upload to Firebase storage):

```
sR.putFile(mFilePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                        String uploadId = mDatabase.push().getKey();
                        mDatabase.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                        mProgressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                    }
                });
```

Questions:

1. As you can see, I reset the ProgressBar to 0 in the `onSucess` method, which makes the ProgressBar never visually reach 100%. Is this the correct approach or should the reset be delayed, so the user sees `100%` for a moment? I found no best practices.
2. Should I disable the upload button as long as the upload is running?

Edit:

Is this sufficient to delay the Progressbar?

```
sR.putFile(mImageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                            }
                        }, 500);

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                        String uploadId = mDatabase.push().getKey();
                        mDatabase.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 2):

The better a user is lead by the user interface, the better he thinks of the app's quality in general.

1. I think you should. I always let bars display 100% for about 300 ms, before I hide them (animated: 300 ms animation duration). I think it is much more user friendly than just hiding them right away.
2. You either should disable the upload button while uploading (better) or tell the user that the upload is perfoming, when it is being tapped.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I actually don't know how to properly delay the ProgressBar. Should i use handler.postDelayed for this?

Comment: Yep. I usually use handlers to post runnables delayed. Best way to do it, since the visibility and animations must be managed on the main thread. Just make sure you create your handler instance on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot edit comments after 5 minutes or post code in comments, here is a better explanation of what I was telling in the comment, that I couldn't save…

I mean it this way:

```
class AsyncController implements Runnable {
    public static final long DefaultDelay = 300;

    private final Handler mainThreadHandler;
    private final Runnable runIfFinished;
    private final long delay;

    public AsyncController(Handler mainThreadHandler, Runnable runIfFinished, long delayMS) {
        this.mainThreadHandler = mainThreadHandler;
        this.runIfFinished = runIfFinished;
        this.delay = delayMS > -1 ? delayMS : DefaultDelay;
    }

    public void run () {
        // do async stuff
        if (mainThreadHandler!=null && runIfFinished!=null) {
            mainThreadHandler.postDelayed(runIfFinished, delay);
        }
    }
}

class YourActivity extends Activity {

(... Methods ...)

    public onClick (View v) {
        AsyncController ac=new AsyncController(new Handler(), new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                // hide progress bar
            }
        }, 300);
        new Thread(ac).start();
    }

(... Methods ...)

}
```

But this is a lot of boilerplate code you don't need to type, if you use Android's AsyncTask. Consider to look up a tutorial and use that. The only thing you would do is create the handler and post your runnable delayed, which hides your progress bar.

Comment: Woah, that looks super complicated. I have no experience with AsynTask or Handler yet, but why can't i just use `handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {...})` and reset it in there?

Comment: Can you take a look into my updated question when you find time? I posted my approach there.

Comment: Well, it basically works the way you did it. You need to make sure that the Handler object is being instanciated on the main (UI) thread. Else you could end up in a crash. I just am not sure on which thread your callback methods get fired and neither can be you (just think about what happens, if they update the firebase framework). Tip: Use the "final" keyword wherever possible (configure the AS inspections accordingly) and see how you can modify your code. Then create the handler object in code that you are sure about that it runs on the UI thread.

Comment: Ok now I am really confused. It' probably better if I don't use the delay at all. I am a beginner